# flink kubernetes operator high availability relation to job manager

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to use flink kubernetes operator with local minikube kubernetes. What I understand from the flink high availability docs is that the Job Manager replicas is the main thing we are concerned. However, when I override the helm chart values for flink operator installation, I get x number of flink-kubernetes-operator replicas instead of job managers.

Flink operator tools feels it abstract away many things but I can't find answers to topics such as how to deploy replications in different pods or operator itself do it implicitly.

What would be the role of flink kubernetes operator in above explained scenario?

Thanks in advance.

```bash
kubectl get all
NAME                                             READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/flink-kubernetes-operator-64478576b7-5vm4g   1/1     Running   0          8m22s
pod/flink-kubernetes-operator-64478576b7-lpzr7   1/1     Running   0          84m
pod/flink-kubernetes-operator-64478576b7-mk5vr   1/1     Running   0          84m
pod/rule-calculation-engine-5b8474c99b-ln2gb     1/1     Running   0          8m22s
pod/rule-calculation-engine-taskmanager-1-1      1/1     Running   0          7m59s

NAME                                   TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)             AGE
service/rule-calculation-engine        ClusterIP   None            <none>        6123/TCP,6124/TCP   8m22s
service/rule-calculation-engine-rest   ClusterIP   10.102.22.170   <none>        8081/TCP            8m22s

NAME                                        READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
deployment.apps/flink-kubernetes-operator   3/3     3            3           84m
deployment.apps/rule-calculation-engine     1/1     1            1           8m22s

NAME                                                   DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
replicaset.apps/flink-kubernetes-operator-64478576b7   3         3         3       84m
replicaset.apps/rule-calculation-engine-5b8474c99b     1         1         1       8m22s
```

FlinkDeployment yaml

```bash
apiVersion: flink.apache.org/v1beta1
kind: FlinkDeployment
metadata:
  name: rule-calculation-engine
  namespace: flink
spec:
  image: rule-calculation:v1.0.0
  imagePullPolicy: Never

  flinkVersion: v1_17

  serviceAccount: flink
  jobManager:
    resource:
      memory: "1024m"
      cpu: 0.5
  taskManager:
    resource:
      memory: "2048m"
      cpu: 1
  job:
    jarURI: local:///opt/flink/job.jar
    parallelism: 1
    upgradeMode: stateless
    state: running
```

values.yaml to override operator installation which is stated that it overrides config both for operator and also job/task managers

```bash
.............
# Replicas must be 1 unless operator leader election is configured
replicas: 3
.............
defaultConfiguration:
  flink-conf.yaml: |+
    # Flink Config Overrides
   
  kubernetes.operator.leader-election.enabled: true
  kubernetes.operator.leader-election.lease-name: flink-operator-lease
  kubernetes.cluster-id: k8s-ha-app
  high-availability.type: kubernetes
  high-availability.storageDir: local:///opt/flink
.............
```

Also how do one knows which keys values are available for overwriting these yaml files? Honestly, was able to find these through only example config files instead of an official doc stating that this helm chart has these keys available.